# How do I render question mark in React component as I get the below symbol instead

Tags: reactjs, rendering

[image]
I have a RadioButtonGroup component which has:

### Are you local?

tag  and two RadioButton components underneath.
The question mark inside h2 tag is not showing right. Any idea why?
Thanks, Er

Comment: What question mark is not showing? There is a question mark in "Are you local?". Can you also give some code so can a better understanding of what is wrong?

Comment: please provide some code, so it will be helpful to find the issue

Comment: Yes, the question mark that is inside "Are you local?"

Comment: return (
            <div className="Apps">
                <h2>Are you local? </h2>
                <div className="radio-btn-container" style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                   
                   <RadioButton/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to your font so can you please change your font and try again?

Comment: @Niral Oza how do I change the font?

Comment: Please add your css in question and also you can check your css which font used

Comment: Thanks @ NIral Oza, I was using Century Gothic font and that was  causing the problem.